# While iterating over a collections of Java objects--how can I mutate current object?

Tags: java, iterator

I will be using an iterator to loop through a collection of objects in Java. I am a little confused about using an Iterator however (used to using for each loop).  let say I have code like this:

```
Iterator<Organization> orgIter = orgs.iterator();
while (orgIter.hasNext()) {
    Organization orgObj = orgIter.next();
    orgObj.setChildOrgsTree(generateOrgChildTree(orgObj, new ArrayList<Organization>()));
}
```

I create a new object and then change the fields inside the object.  My plan was to then set the original object I formed the iteroter out equal to a List of this Object that I create (List is not shown above, but I just figured out that I would need it).

But it would be so much easier if I didn't have to create a new Object to do all of this. Is there a way I can get the current object and mutate that?

Comment: Your wording is confusing.... your code is functionally identical to your accepted answer.  In both cases, the only objects being created are the ArrayLists, and those would be distinct for each Organization instance.  This is the way to go!

Comment: I am confused, I am creating on Organization object and setting it equal to the next iteration.  I guess since that is a reference variable, I am still mutating the same physical memory object...

Comment: There's a difference between declaring a variable and creating an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(Organization org : orgs)
    org.setChildOrgsTree(generateOrgChildTree(org, new ArrayList<Organization>());
```

Comment: +1 This is the way to go. Use a foreach loop, because you're not modifying `orgs`, just modifying the elements *of* `orgs`.

Comment: I guess that is what I should do...  I was trying to expand my repotoire a little bit, but best to do what I can.

Answer (score 3):

If your iterator iterates over a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) instance, then there are fewer restrictions. As long as you do not change the structure of the list, you can do whatever you wish with the object returned by [`Iterator.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29). Of course, the class of that specific object should allow it to be modified, but I presume that you can add the necessary code...

On the other hand, the only list structure modification that is allowed without invalidating the Iterator object, is to remove the current element using [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29), which, incidentally, is an optional operation. If you try to modify the list directly then the iterator will be invalidated and you will get a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) the next time you try to use it.

Additionally, if you are iterating over a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), you are generally far more constrained: depending on the details of the actual `Set` implemenation, you are not generally able to modify arbitrary fields in your objects. For example, the value returned by `hashCode()` should not change once an object has been inserted in a `HashSet`...

As a sidenote, `for-each` loops in Java are just syntactic sugar for using an `Iterator`. If you are not going to use `Iterator.remove()`, just use a `for-each` loop instead of the explicity iterator and be done with it.

Comment: He didn't say he had a `List` though (just that he had a `Collection`), and changing an object that you've stored in a `Set` is very bad if you change a field that is used in the `hashCode` computation (when using `HashSet`) or the `Comparable` computation (when using `TreeSet`).  Doing so would break `Set` semantics, as the value could no longer be located in the set.

Comment: @MarkPeters: agreed, I assumed that the OP was using a List, since the word `Set` is nowhere in the question. I'll update my answer...